# ES6 js code not working in IE 11 for map()

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I have this piece code works fine in Chrome but not in IE 11.
I guess this is ES6 syntax but not very sure.

```
var buf2Hex = function(buffer) {
    //return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(5).join('00').concat(buffer.data.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');

    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer.data), x=>('00'+x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}
```

The commented line is the one i tried but not work.

How to make it work for IE please ?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I don't believe the problem is [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example), it has been supported since IE9, yes, [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)(`=>()`) are ES6 and are not supported by IE (but I think you figured that out already)

Comment: Regarding the error, i got this in IE: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=MyCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined   If i take out this function, the pages loads without error.

Comment: I expect you're getting another error as well. Specifically, a syntax error. As Patrick already stated, IE 11 doesn't support arrow functions. You'll have to use a normal function expression.

Comment: Yes i do gets another error, the main webpage is not finishing loading, but nothing shows up in console. Since the commented out line in my post is the only change, i assume my version of normal function is not correct. Looking for help on that.

Comment: Let me reply to those who gives me negative points: yes maybe i don't know how to describe the problem clearly, as i'm still learning js. But i've show you guys the working version for ES6, and my non-working version for ES5. I'm looking for an answer just to convert it. How difficult it is for some of you to understand the problem ? Being picky but not solving the problem is a shame on you, not on me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var buf2Hex = function(buffer) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer.data), function(x) {
        return ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join('');
    //return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer.data), x=>('00'+x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}
```